# How to insert blank value instead of NULL mysql

Tags: mysql, vb.net, null

I want mysql to store blank value into a field, if a `NULL` value occurs into the record.

How to set a default field value as an empty string or blank value instead of `NULL`.

For example I want `" "` instead of `NULL`.

Comment: What insert statement have you tried and what error did you receive when specifying `''` as a parameter?

Answer (score 1):

You can provide a **default** value with the `DEFAULT` keyword like that:

```
CREATE TABLE example4 (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    sometext VARCHAR(20) DEFAULT ' '
);

INSERT INTO example4 (id) VALUES
(NULL);

SELECT * FROM example4;
```

This will return

```
id | sometext
-------------
1  |
```

The content of sometext is a blank, not `NULL`

**Note**:

If you insert explicitly a `NULL` value into this column, then this NULL value will be stored:

```
INSERT INTO example4 (id, sometext) VALUES
(NULL, NULL);
```

**[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/858e65/1)**

see the column definition part of the manual page to [CREATE TABLE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table.html):

```
column_definition:
    data_type [NOT NULL | NULL] [DEFAULT default_value]
      [AUTO_INCREMENT] [UNIQUE [KEY] | [PRIMARY] KEY]
      [COMMENT 'string']
      [COLUMN_FORMAT {FIXED|DYNAMIC|DEFAULT}]
      [STORAGE {DISK|MEMORY|DEFAULT}]
      [reference_definition]
```